# SharePoint User Profile Service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I would like to know if it is possible to configure A 2013 SharePoint user profile service for 2 different domains. This company is owned by a another company in a different Domain and I want to configure the user profile service to pick up those users.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. If it is a two-way trust, the existing sync account can be delegated the appropriate rights. If there is not a two-way trust in place, or another trust configuration that prevents delegation of the existing account, you can establish a new sync account in the other domain, then create a new sync connection in the UPSA.